# What am I doing wrong while installing AMP?

Tags: php, apache, localhost

So I am following TheNewBostons video guide:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQCIZOv1su0&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDdCg0Jli_WTZd5JIliDY62&index=3

(On how to manually install Apache, php and MySQL)

Getting to the 3rd video where I am about to make the "Tuna baby!" php file to test it out I get the error "404 Not Found". I don't have Notepad++ so I am just using Notepad and naming it .php at the end. If I only write localhost is says "It works!", so Apache is working.

```
Not Found
The requested URL /tuna.php was not found on this server.
```

The weird thing is that I had no problems while doing this on my main computer but now I am doing it on my laptop and seem to have the problem every time I try doing it. Had to uninstall everything with "Revo Uninstaller" to remove all the traces and so on so this should be a clean install.

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: whatever your site's document root is, you didn't put your tuna file there. but since you've provided no configuration details, that's about the only "help" we can give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Notepad++, saved the file properly as a php file and it worked.